# Wordpress theme crashes when updating header.php on the Editor

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, crash

I am currently working on a website I didn't code in the first place. It was created by someone else on Wordpress using the Sidney Theme and there is no child-theme.

Here is my problem : when I update the header.php file by going to Appearance -> Editor, the website crashes and all the CSS disappears.

Fortunalely, I made a backup of the website so I recovered it.

I never had any problem like this one. It is the first time I post on Stack Overflow so if you need any info just tell me.

The website is under version 5.1.1 of Wordpress.

Here is header.php file if it can help :

```
    <?php
    /**
    * The header for our theme.
    *
    * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div 
    id="content">
    *
    * @package Sydney
    */
    ?><!DOCTYPE html>
    <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <?php if ( ! function_exists( 'has_site_icon' ) || ! has_site_icon() 
    ) : ?>
    <?php if ( get_theme_mod('site_favicon') ) : ?>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo 
    esc_url(get_theme_mod('site_favicon')); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <?php do_action('sydney_before_site'); //Hooked: sydney_preloader() ?>

    <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'sydney' ); ?></a>

<?php do_action('sydney_before_header'); //Hooked: sydney_header_clone() ?>

<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div class="header-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <?php if ( get_theme_mod('site_logo') ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"><img class="site-logo" src="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod('site_logo')); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" /></a>
            <?php else : ?>
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>           
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="btn-menu"></div>
                <nav id="mainnav" class="mainnav" role="navigation">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'fallback_cb' => 'sydney_menu_fallback' ) ); ?>
                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header><!-- #masthead -->

<?php do_action('sydney_after_header'); ?>

<div class="sydney-hero-area">
    <?php sydney_slider_template(); ?>
    <div class="header-image">
        <?php sydney_header_overlay(); ?>
        <img class="header-inner" src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->width ); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
    </div>
    <?php sydney_header_video(); ?>

    <?php do_action('sydney_inside_hero'); ?>
</div>

<?php do_action('sydney_after_hero'); ?>

<div id="content" class="page-wrap">
    <div class="container content-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
```

Comment: What error do you get? 500? Go to the website logs and check what it says in there.

Comment: Hard to say based just on what You posted, but at my previous job a had situation like that as well. There might be a script that checks if anythng was modified in given file. If the checksum of original file is different after edition then You can get 500.

Comment: I tried to check the log but I am not an expert in wordpress developement, I tried to change the wpconfig to get the log file but then the website crashed again.

Answer (score 0):

don't use theme Editor. open your cpanel. go to your theme folder. edit your header file.  then paste your code.
thankyou.

Comment: Okay I am going to try that, I just need to recover the access to the cpanel (the company didn't have them, they are not well organised...)

Comment: So Use File Manager Plugin For Wordpress